# GoogleSignIn.requestPermission show empty popup android

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm working on to build a walking app for step counting. I have followed
the Google Developers [documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started) for setup. The problem is whenever I call  `GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(ActivityStart.this,RC_REQUEST_STEP_COUNT_AND_CONTINUE_SUBSCRIPTION,getGoogleAccount(),fitnessOptions)` It shows an empty loading popup.
And if I do not ask permission and call `Fitness.getRecordingClient` An error occurs (The user must be signed in to make this API call).

Code:

```
public class ActivityStart extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_REQUEST_STEP_COUNT_AND_CONTINUE_SUBSCRIPTION = 101;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION = 100;
    private FitnessOptions fitnessOptions;
    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1001;
    private Button btnPause;
    String[] arrayOf = new String[2];
    private TextView tvSteps;
    private TextView tvDistance;
    private TextView tvTime;
    private TextView tvCalories;
    private TextView tvPace;
    private TextView tvAvgPace;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ).addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ).addDataType(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ).addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ).addDataType(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ).addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();
        arrayOf[0] = Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION;
        //  startSubscription();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(getGoogleAccount(), fitnessOptions)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(ActivityStart.this,
                    RC_REQUEST_STEP_COUNT_AND_CONTINUE_SUBSCRIPTION,
                    getGoogleAccount(),
                    fitnessOptions);
        } else {
            startSubscription(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
        }
        btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
    }

    public void init() {
        tvSteps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSteps);
        tvDistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDistance);
        tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        tvCalories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCalories);
        tvPace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPace);
        tvAvgPace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAvgPace);
    }

    private GoogleSignInAccount getGoogleAccount() {
        return GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions);
    }

    public void startSubscription(DataType dataType) {
        Fitness.getRecordingClient(this, getGoogleAccount())
                // This example shows subscribing to a DataType, across all possible
                // data sources. Alternatively, a specific DataSource can be used.
                .subscribe(dataType)
                .addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
                            Log.i("Success_Subscribe", "Successfully subscribed!");
                            getDataUsingSensor(dataType);
                        }
                )
                .addOnFailureListener(e ->
                        Log.w("failed_Subscribe", "There was a problem subscribing.", e));
    }

    public void getDataUsingSensor(DataType dataType) {
        Fitness.getSensorsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(this, fitnessOptions)).add(new SensorRequest.Builder().setDataType(dataType).setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build(), new OnDataPointListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataPoint(@NonNull DataPoint dataPoint) {
                float steps = Float.parseFloat(dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).toString());
                float distance = Float.parseFloat(dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_DISTANCE).toString());
                float calories = Float.parseFloat(dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_CALORIES).toString());
                float duration = Float.parseFloat(dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_DURATION).toString());
                float speed = Float.parseFloat(dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_SPEED).toString());
                String stepsCount = Float.parseFloat(new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(steps)) + "";
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (RC_REQUEST_STEP_COUNT_AND_CONTINUE_SUBSCRIPTION == requestCode) {
                startSubscription(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
            }
        }
    }


}


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started
```

Comment: Do you have your Internet connection turned on?

Comment: Can you post the logcat output? Maybe there is a stacktrace that could help

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Google Cloud Platform.
2. In the left panel of your project, select OAuth Consent Screen.
3. Scroll down and you'll see Test Users. Here, add the email address of the user.

Hope it works for you.